# Backbone fire an event after models have been 'set' into a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to trigger one event after a batch of models have been added to a collection via the `set` method. I overrode the `set` method, called its parents set method and put a console.log in there, and it seemed to be triggering for every model that was trying to be added into the colleciton.

```
class MyCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    set: ->
        super
        console.log('set called')
```

I could not determine why this was happening, but to move forward I decided to use underscores `debounce` method to group these together and fire an event afterwards. This is what I came up with

```
class MyCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    initialize: ->
        @batchComplete = _.debounce(@_batchComplete, 1000)
        super
        @

    _batchComplete: =>
            if not window.test
                    window.test = @

            if window.test is @
                    console.log 'SAME AS PREVIOUS'
            else
                    console.log 'DIFFERENT', window.test, @

            window.test = @ 
            @trigger('setComplete')

    set: ->        
            super
            @batchComplete()
            @
```

I have created an instance of this collection and trying to use the set method

```
c = new MyCollection
c.set([{...},{...},{...}])
```

My expectation of this was for `window.test` to equal `@` however they seem to be referencing different locations. This is a sample output in the console

```
> DIFFERNT MyCollection, MyCollection
> DIFFERNT MyCollection, MyCollection
```

I dont understand why `window.test` is not the same as `@`. As a result of each iteration not being the same, it means that it is not calling the same `debounce` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really calling `set` on an empty collection then you could use [`reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) instead:

> **reset** `collection.reset([models], [options])`
>
> Adding and removing models one at a time is all well and good, but sometimes you have so many models to change that you'd rather just update the collection in bulk. Use **reset** to replace a collection with a new list of models (or attribute hashes), triggering a single `"reset"` event at the end.

So you could:

```
c = new MyCollection
c.on('reset', (collection) -> ...)
c.set([{...},{...},{...}])
```

and you'd get one `'reset'` event at the end.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EVxM7/

If `reset` isn't appropriate then you could use [`_.after`](http://underscorejs.org/#after):

> **after** `_.after(count, function)`
>
> Creates a version of the function that will only be run after first being called **count** times.

So you could do things like this:

```
a = array_of_models
c = new Collection
c.on('add', _.after(a.length, (model, collection) -> ...)
c.set(a)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6SnSS/

You could also override `set` and trigger a custom event and listen for that custom event to know when `set` has done its work:

```
class C extends Backbone.Collection
    set: ->
        super
        @trigger('batch-done', @)

c = new C
c.on('batch-done', (collection) ->
    console.log('All done', collection.toJSON())
)
c.set([ ... ])
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YytvS/